# How to add positioning in when calling JSONobject in JSON arrray

Tags: json, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Here is my code

```js
Main .java file :


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
   
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> arr;
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add("Dedicated To.. ");
        arr.add("1. A cheerful heart");
        arr.add("2. A new commandment");
        arr.add("3. A pure heart");
 try {
   object.put("1. A cheerful heart"," you ");
        object.put("2. A new commandment","Welcome");
object.put("2. A new commandment","Welcome");
object.put("3. A pure heart","Heis");

} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final JSONArray keys=object.names();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                try {
                    i.putExtra("text",object.getString(keys.getString(position)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

There some other code to too.

My Doubt is,

Here if you see `arr.add("1. A cheerful heart");` is the one which I am passing to `object.put("1. A cheerful heart"," you ");`.

When I click on Cheerful heart item it should show you on its respectively but it is taking a random value which like `object.put("3. A pure heart","Heis");` i.e; value is passing randomly. IF there are 100 it is taking random values.

So I need help to give positioning When I click on item1 it has to give item1 content in next activity. When I click item2 it should give me Item2 content respectively.

Please, someone, help me how to give positioning when I passing JSON array to JSON object. Also If any help me with Search view integrated into my question well appreciated.

IF loop or for loop is fine, I want I give full code.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: Did you figure it out?